# Disable code completion inside quotes in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-completion

Is there any way to disable Sublime Text 3 firing code completion, when cursor is inside single or double quotes:

[image]

This seems to be pointless behaviour and is a little bit annoying.

I'm using newest stable (3065) Sublime Text 3, with [PHP Completions Kit](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Completions%20Kit) plugin, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that your PHP Completions Kit plugin is probably to blame. I [forked the code on Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/sublime-phpck) if you'd like to follow along.

You can populate the auto-complete dropdown in Sublime by creating a JSON-formatted [`.sublime-completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) file. Essentially, it's a long list of snippets with associated triggers, the names of which show up in the dropdown and are matched by a fuzzy search method based on what you type. The completions are all [scoped](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#scopes-and-scope-selectors) so they only come up in the desired parts of your code: for example, you wouldn't want standard function names coming up when you're trying to define a class, etc.

Back to the plugin. For several of the completion files, the scope was built up using negative selectors: starting with `source.php` (the base scope for all PHP code), and subtracting unwanted scopes. Once analyzed by Sublime, the completions would show up anywhere except where they were explicitly denied. An example, from `function.sublime-completions`:

```js
"scope": "source.php - variable.other - meta.function.arguments - support.class - entity.other.inherited-class - meta.use - meta.catch - comment.block.documentation.phpdoc"
```

So those were all the places the author **didn't** want these completions to show up. Unfortunately, in these several files, s/he forgot to include the `string` scope, so completions appeared when you were typing strings, clearly undesired behavior. Fortunately, the fix is easy: go through all the completions files, check the scopes for negative selectors, and add `- string` to the end of them. Now, they'll still work exactly the same as before, except the completions won't show up in any kind of string.

Like I said at the top, I forked the project [here](https://github.com/MattDMo/sublime-phpck), and have made the necessary corrections. I've also submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpck/pull/6), so we'll see if/when that gets accepted into the main code base. In the mean time, feel free to clone my repo into your `Packages` directory:

Click on **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up your `Packages` directory. Go to that directory via the command line, then run

```
git clone https://github.com/MattDMo/sublime-phpck.git "PHP Completions Kit"
```

This will clone the repo into a folder named `PHP Completions Kit`, overriding the one installed by Package Control. Keep an eye on the plugin's [Package Control page](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PHP%20Completions%20Kit), and when you see the `Modified` field change from `2014-09-05` (it's in the tooltip if you mouse over the text `3 weeks ago`) to sometime more recent, check the repo to see if it was my pull request that got merged and a new version released, and then you can feel free to delete the new folder in `Packages` and just stick with the Package Control version, as I won't be keeping my repo up-to-date on any new modifications to the package.

### Update

My pull request has been merged, and Package Control has been updated.

Comment: It seems, that even with updated PHP Completions Kit, problem has not been resolved fully. It [looks like](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpck/issues/7#issuecomment-57471236) Sublime Text 3 is firing code completion for [other sources of completions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html#sources-for-completions). Any chance you can handle disabling them as well within this, updated, answer? Or should I ask another question?

Comment: @trejder in your user preferences, add this line (or modify it if it's already there): `"auto_complete_selector": source - comment - string, meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin"`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect, as usually! :]